# How to know the result of the JMeter test from command line?

Tags: jmeter

I would like to know if there any flag for the following command to know the test result on the command line itself?

```
jmeter.bat -n -t  "../Tests/testPlan.jmx" -l "../Tests/testResult.xml"
```

I don't want to open `testResult.xml` to learn if the test is pass or fail.

Regards
Chaitanya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't. You can check all the options available [here](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/get-started.html). Although, if the output is more or less similar you could write a script to automate that process.

Answer (score 3):

[Use Summary properties](http://developer.amd.com/community/blog/2009/03/31/using-apache-jmeter-in-non-gui-mode/)

The Non-GUI mode needs other properties set in order to print to `System.out`. See the blog above.

```
# Write messages to System.out
summariser.out=true
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is some other command-line way: http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD